# how to store Spark Dataframe in hive in uncompressed text format

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to store dataframe into an external hive table. When I perform the following action:

```
 recordDF.write.option("path", "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/hadoop/hive/warehouse/VerizonProduct").saveAsTable("productstoreHTable")
```

At the hdfs location where the table was supposed to be present instead I get this:

> -rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera          0 2016-12-25 18:58 hadoop/hive/warehouse/VerizonProduct/_SUCCESS
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera        482 2016-12-25 18:58 hadoop/hive/warehouse/VerizonProduct/part-r-00000-0acdcc6d-893b-4e9d-b1d6-50bf02bea96a.snappy.parquet
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera        482 2016-12-25 18:58 hadoop/hive/warehouse/VerizonProduct/part-r-00001-0acdcc6d-893b-4e9d-b1d6-50bf02bea96a.snappy.parquet
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera        482 2016-12-25 18:58 hadoop/hive/warehouse/VerizonProduct/part-r-00002-0acdcc6d-893b-4e9d-b1d6-50bf02bea96a.snappy.parquet
>
> -rw-r--r--   3 cloudera cloudera        482 2016-12-25 18:58 hadoop/hive/warehouse/VerizonProduct/part-r-00003-0acdcc6d-893b-4e9d-b1d6-50bf02bea96a.snappy.parquet

How do I store it as uncompressed text format?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add `format` option:

```
recordDF.write.option("path", "...").format("text").saveAsTable("...")
```

or

```
recordDF.write.option("path", "...").format("csv").saveAsTable("...")
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work: 
`WARN hive.HiveExternalCatalog: Couldn't find corresponding Hive SerDe for data source provider text.`

Answer (score 1):

The above solution with format csv, threw a warning "Couldn't find corresponding Hive SerDe for data source provider csv.". The table is not created in the desired way. One solution could be create an external table as below  
   `sqlContext.sql("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(col1 int,col2 string) STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/path/in/hdfs'")` .

Then 
    `dataFrame.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("/path/in/hdfs")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.option("fileFormat", "texfile")`. Look at [Specifying storage format for Hive tables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html#specifying-storage-format-for-hive-tables)